# Newbie doubts on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So my program has 2 models, `Cars` and `Payments`, where Payments is `belong_to` Cars and is a one-to-many relationship.

I want to create a feature for calculating the accounts by going through the Payments' value and within a specific period. The user will give 2 inputs, `start_date` and `end_date`, then the program will calculate the total profit and expenses with the payments made within the period stated.

My **question** is, for the account part, should I create a Account Controller or creating new routes in the existing `payment_controller` to calculate for the accounts part. If creating an Account Controller, how do I access the payments model from the Account Controller?

refer to this link for my project.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10960981/VKVINAUTO.rar

Or you could suggest a better method for me to proceed.

Comment: When you say "payments" do you mean any transactions on the vehicle?  You'll need to include original commission, dealer prep.  Will the seller accept part exchange vehicles?  All these different types of charges will need to be categorised so not only do you need an account controller, you likely need an account model (which the payment will also `belong_to`)  to produce the p & l and balance sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GIT**

Firstly, you need to consider the use of [`git`](http://git-scm.com/) or another [Software Configuration Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) system - which will give you the ability to properly manage the various elements of your code & its respective versioning.

Specifically, you shouldn't be posting `RAR` file with your code. You'll be much better suited to using the likes of [`GitHub`](https://github.com/) or [`BitBucket`](https://bitbucket.org/) to store & share the relevant snippets of code you need help with.

You'll be best suited looking up about `git` with [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/96-git-on-rails):

[image]

---

**Fix**

To answer your question about your fix, here's what you have to consider:

```
#config/routes.rb
root: "payments#index"
resources :cars do
  resources :payments
end

#app/models/car.rb
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :payments do
       def dates begin, end
           where("created_at >= begin AND created_at <= end")
       end
   end
end

#app/models/payment.rb
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :car
end

#app/controllers/cars_controller.rb
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @car = Car.find params[:car_id]
      @payments = @car.payments
      if params[:begin].present? && params[:end].present?
          @payments = @car.payments.dates(params[:begin], params[:end])
      end
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/views/payments/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag car_payments_index(@car), method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :begin %>
    <%= text_field_tag :end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go">
<% end %>
```

This will essentially "refresh" the payments index page, determining the dates as you require.

---

**Models**

If you want to access the `Payment` model from the `accounts_controller`, you'll just be able to reference it by invoking it:

```
#app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @payments = Payment.all
   end
end
```

You'll want to read up on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which Rails is built on. This will show you the relationship between `Models`, `views` and `Controller` -- specifically, with them being interchangeable / exclusive